# soap metro dump

Tags: java, soap, microsoft-metro

I'M using -Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true to dump my SOAP requests and responses.

In my Glassfish console, I can see that a login has generated 6 log entries :

3 Request message received in Tube and 3 Request message processed in Tube.
Each of these SOAP "messages" have a different instance ID... :

Could these messages be considered duplicates or normal?

```
INFO: Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter ]   Instance [ 813 ] Engine [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl@37100007 ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-1234(1) ]:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns16:loginRequest xmlns:dm="http://dm.app" xmlns:doc="http://doc.app"    xmlns:rights="http://rights.app" xmlns:alert="http://alert.app" xmlns:program="http://program.app" xmlns:med="http://med.app" xmlns:mon="http://mon.app" xmlns:device="http://device.app" xmlns:mail="http://mail.app" xmlns:report="http://report.app" xmlns:event="http://event.app" xmlns:wscommon="http://wscommon.app" xmlns:cc="http://cc.app" xmlns:form="http://form.app" xmlns:db="http://db.app" xmlns:ns16="http://patient.app">
<ns16:user>ye006</ns16:user>
<ns16:password>ye006</ns16:password>
<ns16:language>en</ns16:language>
<ns16:mode>standard</ns16:mode>
</ns16:loginRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

INFO: Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter ]    Instance [ 812 ] Engine [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl@37100007 ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-1234(1) ]:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns16:loginRequest xmlns:dm="http://dm.app" xmlns:doc="http://doc.app"  xmlns:rights="http://rights.app" xmlns:alert="http://alert.app" xmlns:program="http://program.app" xmlns:med="http://med.app" xmlns:mon="http://mon.app" xmlns:device="http://device.app" xmlns:mail="http://mail.app" xmlns:report="http://report.app" xmlns:event="http://event.app" xmlns:wscommon="http://wscommon.app" xmlns:cc="http://cc.app" xmlns:form="http://form.app" xmlns:db="http://db.app" xmlns:ns16="http://patient.app">
<ns16:user>ye006</ns16:user>
<ns16:password>ye006</ns16:password>
<ns16:language>en</ns16:language>
<ns16:mode>standard</ns16:mode>
</ns16:loginRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

INFO: Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter ] Instance [ 811 ] Engine [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl@37100007 ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-1234(1) ]:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns16:loginRequest xmlns:dm="http://dm.app" xmlns:doc="http://doc.app" xmlns:rights="http://rights.app" xmlns:alert="http://alert.app" xmlns:program="http://program.app" xmlns:med="http://med.app" xmlns:mon="http://mon.app" xmlns:device="http://device.app" xmlns:mail="http://mail.app" xmlns:report="http://report.app" xmlns:event="http://event.app" xmlns:wscommon="http://wscommon.app" xmlns:cc="http://cc.app" xmlns:form="http://form.app" xmlns:db="http://db.app" xmlns:ns16="http://patient.app">
<ns16:user>ye006</ns16:user>
<ns16:password>ye006</ns16:password>
<ns16:language>en</ns16:language>
<ns16:mode>standard</ns16:mode>
</ns16:loginRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

INFO: Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ServerMUTube ] Instance [ 810 ] Engine [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl@37100007 ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-1234(1) ]:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns16:loginRequest xmlns:dm="http://dm.app" xmlns:doc="http://doc.app" xmlns:rights="http://rights.app" xmlns:alert="http://alert.app" xmlns:program="http://program.app" xmlns:med="http://med.app" xmlns:mon="http://mon.app" xmlns:device="http://device.app" xmlns:mail="http://mail.app" xmlns:report="http://report.app" xmlns:event="http://event.app" xmlns:wscommon="http://wscommon.app" xmlns:cc="http://cc.app" xmlns:form="http://form.app" xmlns:db="http://db.app" xmlns:ns16="http://patient.app">
<ns16:user>ye006</ns16:user>
<ns16:password>ye006</ns16:password>
<ns16:language>en</ns16:language>
<ns16:mode>standard</ns16:mode>
</ns16:loginRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

INFO: Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ServerMUTube ] Instance [ 809 ] Engine [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl@37100007 ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-1234(1) ]:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns16:loginRequest xmlns:dm="http://dm.app" xmlns:doc="http://doc.app" xmlns:rights="http://rights.app" xmlns:alert="http://alert.app" xmlns:program="http://program.app" xmlns:med="http://med.app" xmlns:mon="http://mon.app" xmlns:device="http://device.app" xmlns:mail="http://mail.app" xmlns:report="http://report.app" xmlns:event="http://event.app" xmlns:wscommon="http://wscommon.app" xmlns:cc="http://cc.app" xmlns:form="http://form.app" xmlns:db="http://db.app" xmlns:ns16="http://patient.app">
<ns16:user>ye006</ns16:user>
<ns16:password>ye006</ns16:password>
<ns16:language>en</ns16:language>
<ns16:mode>standard</ns16:mode>
</ns16:loginRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

INFO: Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube ] Instance [ 808 ] Engine [ com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl@37100007 ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-1234(1) ]:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns16:loginRequest xmlns:dm="http://dm.app" xmlns:doc="http://doc.app" xmlns:rights="http://rights.app" xmlns:alert="http://alert.app" xmlns:program="http://program.app" xmlns:med="http://med.app" xmlns:mon="http://mon.app" xmlns:device="http://device.app" xmlns:mail="http://mail.app" xmlns:report="http://report.app" xmlns:event="http://event.app" xmlns:wscommon="http://wscommon.app" xmlns:cc="http://cc.app" xmlns:form="http://form.app" xmlns:db="http://db.app" xmlns:ns16="http://patient.app">
<ns16:user>ye006</ns16:user>
<ns16:password>ye006</ns16:password>
<ns16:language>en</ns16:language>
<ns16:mode>standard</ns16:mode>
</ns16:loginRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Found the answer,
Actually it's the same request/response pair that has gone through the different pipes and therefore the request/responses are actually printed 3 times.

In order to narrow the output console only a single copy of the request/response pair,
refer to the pipes defined in your system :
com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ServerMUTube, com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter and com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube...

here is the reference:
http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#dumping-soap-messages-on-server